# Why isnt my link yellow

Tags: html, css

So i have a navigation but for some reason my link is not yellow even if it is selected.

```
  <div class="link-selected" id="navbutton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
  <div id="navbutton"><a href="expertise.html">Expertise</a></div>
  <div id="navbutton"><a href="doctors.html">Doctors</a></div>
  <div id="navbutton"><a href="facility.html">Facility</a></div>
  <div id="navbutton"><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></div>

#nav #navbutton{
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    float:left;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
#nav #navbutton a{
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    float:left;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav #navbutton.link-selected{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:#ece60a;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: ID's should be unique in an HTML document. Validate your html, when it returns without errors, check if you still have css problems ( or it may be they have then magically disappeared ;) ) (on a side note: `#nav #navbutton.link-selected a {`....

Answer (score 1):

The `color` property applies to each individual element. The div elements are yellow, but that doesn't matter because the links inside them are `color: #FFF` not `color: inherit`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
.link-selected a{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color:#ece60a;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3f89/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of some text you need to use `color` in css so in you case you want `color: yellow;`